# How to get folder size ignoring hard links?

Tags: files, disk-usage, hard-link, size

I use rsnapshot for backups, which generates a series of folders containing files of the same name. Some of the files are hard linked, while others are separate. For instance, `hourly.1/file1` and `hourly.2/file1` might be hard linked to the same file, while `hourly.1/file2` and `hourly.2/file2` are entirely separate files.

I want to find the amount of space used by the folder `hourly.2` **ignoring** any files which are hard links to files in `hourly.1`. So in the above example, I would want to get the size of file2, but ignore file1.

I'm using bash on linux, and I want to do this from the command line as simply as possible, so no big graphical or other-OS-only solutions please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Total size in bytes of all files in `hourly.2` which have only one link:

```
$ find ./hourly.2 -type f -links 1 -printf "%s\n" | awk '{s=s+$1} END {print s}'
```

From `find` man-page:

```
   -links n
          File has n links.
```

To get the sum in kilobytes instead of bytes, use `-printf "%k\n"`

To list files with different link counts, play around with `find -links +1` (more than one link), `find -links -5` (less than five links) and so on.

Comment: If a file some where is hard link to a file in `hourly2`, your command will procedure wrong answer.

Comment: @Gnouc - Well yes - it depends on how the files end up in `hourly.2`. If they are copied there, they will not have extra links and my command will work. If they are hard-linked, obviously it will fail. I'm assuming new backup-files are copied.

Answer (score 18):

As @Gilles says, since `du` counts only the first of all hardlinks pointing to the same inode it encounters, you can give it directories in a row:

```
$ du -hc --max-depth=0 dirA dirB
29G /hourly.1
 1G /hourly.2
30G total
```

I.e. any file in 'hourly.2' referencing an inode (aka "real" file) already referenced in 'hourly.1', will not be counted.

Comment: According to *du --help*, option *--max-depth=0* is equivalent to *-s*, so above can be shortened as: `$ du -hcs dirA dirB`

Answer (score 14):

If you specifically want the size of the files that are present under `hourly.2` but not under `hourly.1`, you can obtain it a little indirectly with `du`. If `du` processes the same file more than once (even under different names, i.e. hard links), it only counts the file the first time. So what `du hourly.1 hourly.2` reports for `hourly.2` is the size you're looking for. Thus:

```
du -ks hourly.1 hourly.2 | sed -n '2s/[^0-9]*//p'
```

(Works on any POSIX system and most other Unix variants. Assumes that the directory name `hourly.1` doesn't contain any newline.)

Comment: For some strange reason du doesn't always notices hardlinked files on RHEL5 - if I do 'du -sh dir/sub dir' the output for dir is the same as if I just said 'du -sh dir' - not excluding the size of 'dir/sub'.

Answer (score 5):

More simple

```
du -hc --max-depth=1 path/
```

Example

```
9.4G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.21
3.6G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.30
4.2G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.11
1.1G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.4
4.2G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.9
3.0G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.25
3.5G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.20
4.2G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.13
913M    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.5
2.8G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.26
1.4G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.1
2.6G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.28
4.2G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.15
3.8G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.19
327M    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.8
4.2G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.17
3.1G    daily/users/rockspa/home/daily.23
...
```

Comment: Thanks Abdel. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me on the first try on my macOS 10.15. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Awesomely BusyBox's builds of `find` comes without `-printf` support. Here is modification to [@grebneke's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118207):

```
find . -type f -links 1 -exec ls -l {} \;| awk '{s=s+$5} END {print s}'
```